# Everytime I workout my chest my shoulder do all the work

Tags: gym, chest

Always, when I work my chest, my shoulders do all the work. I do the exercises the right way with a lower amount of weights and still my shoulders do all the work.

What is the best way to build chest muscle for a weak chest?

Comment: What exercises are you doing?

Comment: Which exercises? Flat bench, flys, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say this only really applies to the bench, dumbbell or barbell...

Your grip and positioning on the bench is too high. It's probably more around your upper chest.

Here's what I would suggest

- Scoot up on the bench until the bar is unracked at your middle
         chest, and when it's off the bar it hovers around your lower chest.
- Tuck your elbows in
- On the lowering portion of the lift (coming
         down to your chest) Let it lightly touch your chest just under your
         nipple.
- Push back up while trying to bend the bar (figuratively)

Bench press will always incorporate your front shoulders, the key is to bring it down far enough to allow your triceps to catch and engage on the push.

Also try wider grip if you're not feeling the pull around your armpit.

Comment: I agree, try and correct your posture while benching for example by pushing your shoulder blades together and your chest out. This way you can engage your chest musles better.

Comment: @FortAsh - Right forgot to mention tucking shoulder blades back, thanks ;)